# Optimizing NICK binary thresholding

Tags: algorithm, typescript

NICK binary thresholding essentially boils down to a convolution where the kernel at each pixel calculates the sum and squared sum (for the standard deviation). These values are then used in the threshold function to determine whether the grayscale value should be black or white.

A kernel size of 19x19 is pretty common and rather large to apply on a full HD image, especially if it has to be done in semi-real time video.

**Optimizations I've done so far**

The kernel (which is just a bunch of 1's) is a box filter and thus is separable ( M●(h●v) == (M●h)●v ) which reduces the #ops from O(N x M x k²) to O(N x M x (k+k)) but requires additional floating point memory storage to store the intermediate result after the x-pass (M●h).

Next I further reduced the #ops by reusing the sum in both x and y passes. The x-pass calculates

a **b c d e** f g h

a b **c d e f** g h

a b c **d e f g** h

and so on, which is a lot of overlap. I calculate the sum once at the start of each row and then for each consecutive pixel I subtract the element that falls outside the window and add the element that now falls inside the window:

first pixel:
sum1 = a+b+c+d

second pixel:
sum2 = b+c+d+e, which is sum1 -a + e

For larger kernels this saves a huge chunks of operations, making it O(M x k + M x (N-1) x 2)) for the x-pass and O(N x k + N x (M-1) x 2) for the y-pass afterwards.

I've put in some numbers (N=1920, M = 1080, k = 19) which yields the following:

```
Naive convolution                   748569600
Seperable kernels                    78796800
Seperable kernels with reuse of sum   8345400
```

This should be done x2 as it calculates this for both the sum and the squared sum.

This works really well on a desktop computer with a lot of memory available, but my android phone struggles, it's easily 50-100x times slower. I suspect it's the additional large allocation of the buffers required to store the x-pass results. If I don't use separable kernels but do reuse the sum the #ops would come to

```
Naive convolution with reuse of sum  79145640
```

which is again a magnitude of operations higher.

I avoided storing the y-pass result and then iterate over the entire image again to use the sum and sum squared values by applying the threshold immediately, which already helped a lot but I was wondering if there are other approaches to further optimize the algorithm.

**Typescript code**

```
function binaryThresholdNICK(grayscale: Uint8Array, width: number, height: number, wndSize: number, k: number) {
    // keep track of the sum and squared sum of the sliding window
    // this implementation is using a separable kernel so it's divided into 
    // an x-pass which just sums up the row in the window followed by an y-pass
    // which takes these partial sums and sums them in the y direction
    let piSumXPass: Float32Array = new Float32Array(width * height);
    let piSquaredSumXPass: Float32Array = new Float32Array(width * height);

    let halfWndSize = Math.floor(wndSize / 2);

    // doing x-pass and then y-pass is different if the values around the border
    // are taken in account, because x-pass is only done with padding and yet y-pass
    // would take the 0 values from x-pass, compared doing it in 1 go would use the values
    // of the border directly, so removing the border ensures the values are the same as the
    // original slow method without separating the kernels.
    removeBorder(halfWndSize, grayscale, width, height);

    let NP = wndSize * wndSize;

    // keep track of index based on padding
    let padding = halfWndSize;
    let idx = padding * width + padding;
    for (let y: number = padding; y < height - padding; y++) {

        // instead of calculating the sum of the entire row within the window
        // it can be done more efficiently by only calculating the sum for the first 
        // window and then with each shift of the window to the right subtract the element
        // that falls out of the window and add the element that now falls inside the window
        // for large kernels this means only k + 2 * width operations instead of k * width ops
        let sum = 0;
        let sumSquared = 0;
        for (let wnd: number = -halfWndSize; wnd <= halfWndSize; wnd++) {
            let val = grayscale[idx + wnd];
            sum += val
            sumSquared += val * val;
        }
        piSumXPass[idx] = sum;
        piSquaredSumXPass[idx] = sumSquared;

        idx++;

        for (let x: number = padding + 1; x < width - padding; x++) {

            let remVal = grayscale[idx - 1 - halfWndSize];
            let addVal = grayscale[idx + halfWndSize];
            // remove the element that falls out of the range
            sum -= remVal;
            // and add the element that enters the range
            sum += addVal;

            // remove the element that falls out of the range
            sumSquared -= remVal * remVal;
            // and add the element that enters the range
            sumSquared += addVal * addVal;

            piSumXPass[idx] = sum;
            piSquaredSumXPass[idx] = sumSquared;
            idx++;
        }
        idx += 2 * padding;
    }

    // now do the y-pass & immediately use the result at pixel (x,y) to determine
    // the threshold. It follows the same scheme as the x-pass but differs in index
    // calculation because it's vertical

    for (let x: number = padding; x < width - padding; x++) {
        idx = x + padding * width;

        let sum = 0;
        let sumSquared = 0;
        for (let wnd: number = -halfWndSize; wnd <= halfWndSize; wnd++) {
            let cidx = idx + wnd * width;

            sum += piSumXPass[cidx];
            sumSquared += piSquaredSumXPass[cidx]
        }

        // calculate and apply the threshold at pixel
        {
            let m = sum / NP;
            let A = (sumSquared - (m * m)) / NP;
            let T = m + k * Math.sqrt(A);
            if (grayscale[idx] >= T)
                grayscale[idx] = 255;
        }

        idx += width;

        let wEdge = halfWndSize * width;
        for (let y: number = padding + 1; y < height - padding; y++) {

            let cidx = idx - width - wEdge;
            sum -= piSumXPass[cidx];
            sumSquared -= piSquaredSumXPass[cidx];

            cidx = idx + wEdge;
            sum += piSumXPass[cidx];
            sumSquared += piSquaredSumXPass[cidx];

            // now calculate and apply the threshold at each pixel
            {
                let m = sum / NP;
                let A = (sumSquared - (m * m)) / NP;
                let T = m + k * Math.sqrt(A);
                if (grayscale[idx] >= T)
                    grayscale[idx] = 255;
            }

            idx += width;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've implemented a BufferManager pool where each step can request a buffer of specified length and then release it back to the pool. The pool keeps the buffers in memory and by ensuring the buffer sizes remain constant (= the input feed, even though that much space isn't always necessary) the same buffers get reused over and over again. This all but eliminated the huge spikes I would get due to garbage collection. I'm getting a relatively stable processing time now of around 250ms in chrome for a 1920x1080 video feed. If anyone else has some other suggestions that I can try, feel free. I haven't looked into webgl yet, but I think the overhead of transferring the images as textures would already make it not worth it